# Deleting similar columns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, delete-row

In PostgreSQL 8.3, let's say I have a table called `widgets` with the following:

```
 id  | type | count
--------------------
  1  | A    |   21
  2  | A    |   29
  3  | C    |    4
  4  | B    |    1
  5  | C    |    4
  6  | C    |    3
  7  | B    |   14
```

I want to remove duplicates based upon the `type` column, leaving only those with the highest `count` column value in the table.  The final data would look like this:

```
 id  | type | count
--------------------
  2  | A    |   29
  3  | C    |    4  /* `id` for this record might be '5' depending on your query */
  7  | B    |   14
```

I feel like I'm close, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a query that works to get rid of the duplicate columns.

Comment: What about tie-breakers?  If 2+ results have the same count...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is a sql reserve word so it'll have to be escaped somehow. I can't remember the syntax for doing that in Postgres off the top of my head so I just surrounded it with square braces (change it if that isn't correct). In any case, the following should theoretically work (but I didn't actually test it):

```
delete from widgets where id not in (
select max(w2.id) from widgets as w2 inner join 
(select max(w1.[count]) as [count], type from widgets as w1 group by w1.type) as sq
on sq.[count]=w2.[count] and sq.type=w2.type group by w2.[count]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! :)  I wasn't using "count" as the actual column name, this is just a dumbed down example that gets to the heart of what I'm trying to do.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly simpler answer than Asaph's, with EXISTS SQL operator :

```
DELETE FROM widgets AS a 
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM widgets AS b 
   WHERE (a.type = b.type AND b.count > a.count) 
          OR (b.id > a.id AND a.type = b.type AND b.count = a.count))
```

EXISTS operator returns TRUE if the following SQL statement returns at least one record.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, seems to me that this should work:

```
DELETE 
FROM widgets
WHERE type NOT IN 
(
    SELECT type, MAX(count) 
    FROM widgets 
    GROUP BY type
)
```